# script does not prompt for user's input

Tags: powershell

my script does not prompt for the user input when it's executed using 'run with powershell' option. However it does prompt for user's input when I edit the script and run it using the PowerShell ISE tool.

```
$MGWServer = Read-Host 'Enter the name of the server where you want to copy the siteKey file from'

# variable to hold the objects of the list file for copying
$hostNameList = Get-Content D:\Temp\hostlist.txt

# copy file from source to destination
foreach ($hostName in $hostNameList)
{
    $TARGETDIR = "\\$hostName\D$\Temp\"

    Copy-Item -Path "\\$MGWServer\D$\Informatica\PowerCenter\isp\config\keys\siteKey" -Destination "$TARGETDIR\siteKey"
}
```

Comment: What is your question here? You mean when you rightclick on the script and select the "Run with PowerShell" from the contextual menu? It should prompt for user input due to your read-host command, no matter if it's run from PowerShell ISE or by right clicking your script for execution...

Comment: what is  'run with powershell' ? could you please give us a full example of how you're running the script?

Comment: I am trying to run the script to copy a file from one location to the other. Script prompts for the user to input the source server name where the file needs to be copied from and then it takes the hosts list from the hostlist.txt and copies the file to those servers. A right click on the powershell script, there are two options you can choose from. 1) Run with PowerShell 2) Edit. When I run with powershell option, it simply finishes executing the script without letting me to enter source server. However it prompts to enter the value when I choose the Edit option that opens in ISE editor.

Comment: in your powershell console (not ise) what do you get when you run `get-executionpolicy`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce your issue with a minimal script:

```
$X = Read-Host 'Enter your text'
Write-Host $x 
Pause
```

When executed from the 'Run with Powershell' context menu, the script reads from the host and writes it without issues. There might be an invalid character in your script path. Try adding a pause at the beginning and within the loop to review any errors. Also try running it from a Powershell prompt, not ISE.

Comment: it prompts for the user input now. sorry..I don't know why it behaved that way when I tried it yesterday.